# How to make a tutorial modal?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Look at this page [Modal tutorial example](http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/mdm6/), I want to make some like this, I can't find examples for this, someone know how to do it ?

Comment: That one is pretty simple you linked. You can give this a shot if you want: http://www.gamaki-studio.com/envato/tutorialize/

Comment: It seems that it's not free, you know another way?